# What's the difference between Pass-through type Load balancer and Proxy type load balancer in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

GCP load balancing:

```
Network TCP/UDP load balancer:  Pass-through
TCP load balancer: Proxy
```

Except the fact that `TCP load balancer only supports TCP traffic on ports 25, 43, 110, 143, 195, 443, 465, 587, 700, 993, 995, 1883, and 5222.`
 and network load balancer supports all ports and the regional/global difference.

what's the difference between a TCP load balancer on port 5222 and a Network load balancer on port 5222.

How does the `pass-through` and `Proxy` differ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is pass-through load balancer? How is it different from proxy load balancer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43205917/what-is-pass-through-load-balancer-how-is-it-different-from-proxy-load-balancer)

Answer (score 5):

A proxy create a new connexion, so the client is not directly connected to the VM, but to the Proxy, and the Proxy to the VM. That's why, only a set of port/protocol are supported by Proxied connection. Some metadata of the client connection are copied to the proxied connection

On the other hand, the pass-through, or packet forwarding, directly connect the client to the VM without any modification or new connection. All port are supported, it's a simple forward of network traffic. However, there is some limitation, like the a limitation to a region because you can't leverage of the global fiber network with this kind of connection.